# Why is DOMWindow not defined when the constructor of 'this' is DOMWindow

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find DOMWindow but it keeps saying it's undefined. How do I get it?

```
(function() {
    alert(this.constructor); // function DOMWindow() { [native code] }
    alert(DOMWindow); // DOMWindow is undefiend
})();
```

What's wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is `alert(window)` or `alert(window.constructor)`?  `DOMWindow` is the constructor function which creates `window`.

```
(function() {
    alert(this.constructor); // function DOMWindow() { [native code] }
    alert(window); 
    // or...
    alert(window.constructor);
})();

// window shows:
// [Object DOMWindow]

// window.constructor shows:
// function DOMWindow() { [native code] }
```

Comment: It helps, but it's kind of weird that DOMWindow comes up undefined. Do you have any clue why that is??

Comment: @David I don't have an answer. Hopefully another commenter can shed light.

Comment: @David: If you want to know how this is technically possible, have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ac8Vf/). Otherwise, they are probably doing this for security reasons. `window` is not created in the execution environment of the site.